# Vertical line in \halign with interrow spacing - LaTeX error

Tags: tex-core, expansion

```
\documentclass[12pt, russian]{article}

\tracingall
\tracingassigns=5
\tracingmacros=2
\tracingcommands=2
\tracingrestores=1
\tracingstats=0
\tracingoutput=10
\tracinggroups=10
\tracingonline0

\begin{document}
$$
  \left\{
   \hbox\bgroup
    $
     \vcenter\bgroup
      \gdef\withlineskip{\hbox\bgroup$}
      \gdef\endwithlineskip{$\egroup}
      \gdef\\{%
        \cr
        \gdef\withlineskip{\hbox\bgroup \vbox\bgroup \hbox{}\hbox\bgroup$}%
        \gdef\endwithlineskip{$\egroup\egroup\egroup}%
        \gdef\\{\cr}%
      }
      \offinterlineskip
      \halign{
        \hfil\withlineskip # \endwithlineskip
        &\withlineskip {}#{} \endwithlineskip
        &\withlineskip # \endwithlineskip\hfil\ \vrule
        &\withlineskip {} \cdot # \endwithlineskip\cr
        g s_{12} + s_{21} & = & (x_{1}\psi_{1})(t) = \frac{1}{g}U_{1}(t) & (-v) \\
        -s_{11} + v s_{12} + s_{22} & = & (x_{1}\psi_{2})(t) & g \\
        g s_{22} - g s_{11} - v s_{21} & = & \frac{1}{g} (g U_{2}(t) - v U_{1}(t)) & (-1) \\
      }
     \egroup
    $
   \egroup
  \right.
$$
\end{document}
```

My intent is in the title. Can somebody explain me an error LaTeX gives? From `.log` file I understood that something has gone wrong - `\\` has got captured into `\halign`'s template entry. Is that what always happens anyway? How to solve my problem saving the principle of intent?

For those seeking for (almost) correct output, compile this.

```
\documentclass[12pt, russian]{article}

\begin{document}
$$
  \left\{
   \hbox\bgroup
    $
    \displaystyle
     \vcenter\bgroup
      \gdef\withlineskip{$\displaystyle}
      \gdef\endwithlineskip{$}
      \gdef\\{%
        \cr%
      }
      \offinterlineskip
      \halign{%
        \hfil\withlineskip#\endwithlineskip
        &\withlineskip{}#{}\endwithlineskip
        &\withlineskip#\endwithlineskip\hfil\ \vrule
        &\withlineskip{}\cdot#\endwithlineskip\hfil\cr
        g s_{12} + s_{21} & = & (x_{1}\psi_{1})(t) = \frac{1}{g}U_{1}(t) &(-v)\\
        -s_{11} + v s_{12} + s_{22} & = & (x_{1}\psi_{2})(t) &g\\
        g s_{22} - g s_{11} - v s_{21} & = & \frac{1}{g} (g U_{2}(t) - v U_{1}(t)) &(-1)\\
      }
     \egroup
    $
   \egroup
  \right.
$$
\end{document}
```

Did you noticed that third and second rows collide? That's what I'm fighting against. (Okay, found yet another bug in my approach, will correct it after somebody will explain me the error.)

**UPDATE**

That's what I initially meant to have:

```
\documentclass[12pt, russian]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \left\{
   \hbox\bgroup
    $
     \vcenter\bgroup
      % \openup1\jot
      \edef\restoreinterlineskip{%
        \baselineskip=\the\baselineskip
        \lineskip=\the\lineskip
        \lineskiplimit=\the\lineskiplimit
      }
      \gdef\withlineskip{%
        \hbox\bgroup
         \hbox\bgroup
          \hbox\bgroup
           $%
            \displaystyle
      }
      \gdef\endwithlineskip{%
           $%
          \egroup
         \egroup
        \egroup
      }
      \gdef\nextrow{%
        \cr
        \noalign{\xdef\prevrowdepth{\the\prevdepth}\vskip -\prevrowdepth}%
        \gdef\withlineskip{%
          \hbox\bgroup 
           \restoreinterlineskip
           \vbox\bgroup
           \hbox{\vrule width 0pt height 0pt depth \prevrowdepth }%
           \hbox\bgroup
            $
             \displaystyle
        }%
        \gdef\nextrow{%
          \cr
          \noalign{\xdef\prevrowdepth{\the\prevdepth}}%
        }%
      }
      \offinterlineskip
      \halign{
        \hfil\withlineskip # \endwithlineskip
        &\withlineskip {}#{} \endwithlineskip
        &\withlineskip # \endwithlineskip\hfil\ \vrule
        &\withlineskip {} \cdot # \endwithlineskip\cr
        g s_{12} + s_{21} & = & (x_{1}\psi_{1})(t) = \frac{1}{g}U_{1}(t) & (-v) \nextrow
        -s_{11} + v s_{12} + s_{22} & = & (x_{1}\psi_{2})(t) & g \nextrow
        g s_{22} - g s_{11} - v s_{21} & = & \frac{1}{g} (g U_{2}(t) - v U_{1}(t)) & (-1) \nextrow
      }
      \egroup
    $
   \egroup
  \right.
  \Longrightarrow 0 = 0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

No manual inter-row skip choice! :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe that's question for you, since you are experienced with tables (I have just got to know that you are an author of `longtable` package).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The gauntlet has been thrown!

Comment: Your code does not compile for me.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Of course it does not. The whole story is about why and how to correct it. It's not MWE, it's MNWE. Also, I corrected the stupid error with missing `$`. Please copy-paste it again.

Comment: What is it as mixture? This is `\halign` primitive inside LaTeX. Use LaTeX only or use TeX. And the answer: replace `\\ ` to `\cr` in your mixing code. And read the TeX messages carefully.

Comment: @wipet That's after all my personal \\! And what is wrong with using `\halign` in LaTeX? LaTeX is just a set of macros after all.

Comment: The problem is that the `\gdef`s are part of the first column after `\cr`. They are processed after the first `\hfil\whitlineskip` from first column is expanded. So the `\endwithlineskip` from first column doesn't match with the `\withlineskip`.

Comment: @wipet Thank you very much! How stupid I was (well, and still am, since don't sure I understood it properly and can correct without simply adding more group nesting to first definitions of `\withlineskip` and `\endwithlineskip`)! Could you please just retype your comment as answer so I could accept it?

Comment: @AndrewZabavnikov since you pinged me by name:-) using TeX primitives in a latex document is just wrong. It may work sometimes, but latex isn't just a set of macros, it's a language that's implemented using macros but exposing implementations is always a bad practice even when it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `\gdef`s are part of the first column after `\cr`. They are processed after the first `\hfil\whitlineskip` from first column is expanded. So the `\endwithlineskip` from first column doesn't match with the `\withlineskip`.

I don't know what were the requirement. May be only to insert blank line between rows. Then the `\noalign{\bigskip}` after `\cr` solves it. But this is plain TeX approach and I don't understand why it is surrounded by LaTeX's commands.

Answer (score 2):

Is it something like this you are after (LaTeX syntax)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \begin{array}{rl|l}
    gs_{12} + s_{21}            & = (x_1\psi_1)(t) = \dfrac1g U_1(t) & {}\cdot(-v)\\
    -s_{11} + vs_{12} + s_{22}  & = (x_1\psi_2)(t)                  & {}\cdot g\\
    gs_{22} - gs_{11} - vs_{21} & = \dfrac1g (gU_2(t) - vU_1(t))     & {}\cdot (-1)\\
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the TeX primitive using plain-format, one could whip up a little something like:

```
$$
  \left\{\,
  \vcenter{
    \let\DS\displaystyle
    \mathsurround=0pt
    \def\cr{\crcr\noalign{\nointerlineskip}}
    \def\invisiblethingamabob{%
      \vrule height\baselineskip depth.6\baselineskip width0pt}
    \halign{\invisiblethingamabob $\DS\hfil #$& $\DS{}#\hfil\ \vrule $&
    $\;\DS{}\cdot #\hfil$\crcr
    gs_{12} + s_{21}            &= (x_1\psi_1)(t) = {1\over g} U_1(t) & (-v)\cr
    - s_{11} + vs_{12} + s_{22} &= (x_1\psi_2)(t)                     & g \cr
    gs_{22} - gs_{11} - vs_{21} &= {1\over g} (gU_2(t) - vU_1(t))     & (-1)\cr
  }}
  \right.
$$
```

[image]

Comment: Gotta love the `\invisiblethingamabob` thingy. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You're doing too much work for something that in LaTeX is quite straightforward.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}>{{}}l |@{} >{{}\cdot}l@{}}
g s_{12} + s_{21}              &= (x_{1}\psi_{1})(t) = \frac{1}{g}U_{1}(t) & (-v) \\[2ex]
-s_{11} + v s_{12} + s_{22}    &= (x_{1}\psi_{2})(t)                       & g    \\[2ex]
g s_{22} - g s_{11} - v s_{21} &= \frac{1}{g} (g U_{2}(t) - v U_{1}(t))    & (-1)
\end{array}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

No, I won't remove this answer even if you ask for it.

Why don't your macros work? You're trying to do things in the most complicated way.

Here's a more or less straightforward realization in Plain TeX.

```
\def\frac#1#2{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\over#2}}

$$
\left\{
\vcenter{
  \tabskip=0pt
  \offinterlineskip
  \halign{\strut\hfil$#$&${}#$\hfil&\hskip3pt\vrule#&${}\cdot#$\hfil\cr
  g s_{12} + s_{21}&             = (x_{1}\psi_{1})(t) = \frac{1}{g}U_{1}(t)&& (-v)\cr
  \omit&& height1.5ex&\omit\cr
  -s_{11} + v s_{12} + s_{22}&   = (x_{1}\psi_{2})(t)&&                       g\cr
  \omit&& height1.5ex&\omit\cr
  g s_{22} - g s_{11} - v s_{21}&= \frac{1}{g} (g U_{2}(t) - v U_{1}(t))&&    (-1)\cr
  }
}
\right.
$$
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: I was so close! My mad LaTeX skillz are improving ^_^

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call `{@{}r@{}>{{}}l |@{} >{{}\cdot}l@{}}` “straightforward” ;)

Comment: @morbusg Yes, it is: `@{}` does no space at the left; then we want a right aligned column; then a left aligned column with correct spacing for the relation symbol (`@{}>{{}}l`) in the same fashion as `amsmath`'s `align`; then a rule, with no space after it, because we add the spacing before the binary operator `\cdot`; a left aligned column and no space after the array.

Comment: Is it right to have inline-style fashion fractions here?

Comment: @AndrewZabavnikov Yes, I think so. Compare with morbusg table and decide.

Comment: @egreg Do you know what editors do in these cases - do they use inline fractions?

Comment: @AndrewZabavnikov I really can't say: it's a style decision. Since it's the only fraction in the line and is very simple, setting it in display style makes it almost undecipherable. Either you use `\dfrac{U_1(t)}{g}` or `\frac{1}{g}U_1(t)`; but this is just my opinion.

Comment: @egreg At a glance, it seems that making something bigger can't make it undecipherable.